# better way to keep counter other than global variable?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a windows service that does some processing by subscirbing to Message Queue. I have to keep a counter how many times it has received the message and make that counter available on WCF service so other people can query it.

Is there any better way of doing this other than Global Variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a private `static` variable within your class. It almost amounts to the same thing, but at least can have limited exposure to the class it is declared in.

Just to point out that in either case (global/static) you will lose the count on a restart of the service.

Comment: That is illegal in C#. I suppose you were thinking of C or C++?

Comment: @sehe - I meant class. You are quite right in that local static variables are not allowed.